# Append XML file data into CSV file

Tags: python

I have to append my XML file data into a CSV file...How can I do this please help me code is below here.

```
state_file_xml = 'partial.xml'
    context = ET.iterparse(state_file_xml, events=("start","end"))
    nodes = {
        'journal': [],
        'title': [],
        'year': []
    }
    
    element_exist = False
    for event, elem in context:
        if (event == 'start') and (elem.tag == 'article'):
            element_exist = True
    
        if (event == 'end') and (elem.tag in ['journal','year','title']) and element_exist:
            nodes[elem.tag].append(elem.text)
    
        if (event == 'end') and (elem.tag == 'article'):
            element_exist = False
    
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nodes)
```

Comment: By "append", do you mean you want to convert your XML file into a CSV ? Or that it already exists, that you want to append the content of the XML file to it and that it has a given format ?

Answer (score 0):

Just open your CSV file with mode `'a'` then pass that to the call to `to_csv`.

```py
import pandas as pd

fp = open('yourfile.csv', 'a')

nodes = {
    'journal': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
    'title': ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff'],
    'year': [2000, 2002, 2004]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(nodes)
df.to_csv(fp, index=False, header=False)

fp.close()
```